# Why can't I pattern match on generics in Scala using TypeTags

Tags: scala, generics, pattern-matching

I am probably overlooking something but I'm wondering the following.
Using TypeTags in Scala 2.13 I can do this:

```scala
def fun[T: TypeTag](v: List[T]) = {
  v match {
    case v2: List if typeOf[T] =:= typeOf[Option[Int]] => {
      val v3 = v2.asInstanceOf[List[Option[Int]]]
      v3.map(x: Int => ...)
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

In this example I can use v3 with the correct type and I can be sure that the cast succeeds since I checked it before via the TypeTag. But it feels broken since I have to enter the type twice (once in the check and once in the cast) which can lead to typo errors and it seems like unnecessary boilerplate.

So is there any reason why the compiler doesn't support me writting

```scala
def fun[T: TypeTag](v: List[T]) = {
  v match {
    case v3: List[Option[Int] => {
      v3.map(x: Int => ...)
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

and then fills in the check and the cast for me?

It seems straight forward to me, but, as I said, I'm probably overlooking something.

Thanks in advance for any helpful explanation.

Answer (score 4):

> But it feels broken since I have to enter the type twice

This is just the way it works, since it's implemented with an if guard. While you can use type matching to narrow the type of the right-hand side of a match  (like `case x: Int`), this only works for non-erased types. The if guard can correctly narrow a successful match to the result you expect by comparing type tags, but it *doesn't* narrow the type of the right-hand side, and for good reason. Since the if guard is just a Boolean expression, the compiler would need to do quite a bit of gymnastics to determine your intention to filter by type. Imagine you wrote:

```
if typeOf[T] =:= typeOf[Option[Int]] || typeOf[T] =:= typeOf[Int]
```

Things can get complicated fairly quickly for the compiler by trying to correctly infer the type this way. Because of this, a cast is necessary.

You *could* sweep some of the casting under the rug by creating an extractor to handle it for you:

```
object TypeMatch {
  def apply[A: TypeTag]: TypeMatch[A] = new TypeMatch[A]
}

class TypeMatch[A: TypeTag] {
  def unapply[B: TypeTag](b: List[B]): Option[List[A]] = {
    if(typeOf[A] =:= typeOf[B]) Option(b.asInstanceOf[List[A]])
    else None
  }
}

def fun[T: TypeTag](v: List[T]) = {
  val OptionInt = TypeMatch[Option[Int]]
  v match {
    case OptionInt(v3) => {
      v3.foreach((x: Option[Int]) => println(x))
    }
    case _ => println("Not List[Option[Int]]")
  }
}
```

This isn't particularly pretty, and I probably wouldn't bother using it unless I was casting over and over again. Unfortunately, the extractor needs to have a stable identifier, so we can't write `case TypeMatch[Option[Int]](list)` or anything like that, but it works:

```
scala> fun(ints)
Some(1)
Some(2)
None
None
Some(10)
Some(20)

scala> fun(strings)
Not List[Option[Int]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I don't agree. Of course you can do more complicated checks (like checking for union types) using pattern guards, but that also holds true for non-generic types (so it can't be the answer).
My question is, why the compiler can't fill in the boilerplate (check and cast) for working around type erasure in the simple case and thereby keep the syntax consistent with the non-generic case?

Comment: @Cornelius probably because the need is very specific and most people didn't need this so far. Also keep in mind that `TypeTag` was an "experimental" feature with some flaws and was not kept in Scala 3.

Comment: @GaëlJ So you are saying that it would in principle be possible? Is it possible using Typeable in Scala 3 then?

Comment: "My question is, why the compiler can't fill in the boilerplate" -- Maybe it theoretically could be, but what I'm saying is that it's a non-trivial feature to implement and the compiler team chose not to do it. Perhaps there's an entirely different way to achieve this in Scala 3, but I focused by answer on `TypeTag` in Scala 2.13 because that was how the question was posed.

Comment: @MichaelZajac You write "Maybe it theoretically could be" which I interpret as you don't really know. But that is exactly my question. Is it theoretically possible but wasn't done or is there some underlying reason why it wasn't done.
Because I personally think this is a quite common issue and I would be very much surprised if it is possible but just wasn't done. At least I would think there would be a proposal to implement such a thing in the compiler if it were possible.

Comment: Perhaps you should amend your question then? For the question "Why can't I pattern match on generics in Scala using TypeTags", the answer is simply "Because it's not a feature of the 2.13 compiler", it just isn't. If you want to know why it isn't a feature, there is no definitive answer unless a maintainer weighs in.